# Acer Aspire 7741z : Function key adjust brightness but displays 10% in Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, laptop, brightness, acer

On my Acer my brightness function key works, but the confirmation display only goes up to about 10%. Also the function key seems to be the only thing that will adjust the brightness. I cannot adjust the brightness from System Settings.